# Avoid duplicate submission of Struts 2 jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

Hi all I've got some jsp pages and im using struts2 to handle my forms.
 After submitting a form by user, the url shown in address bar becomes somthing.action, so when the user refreshes the page, the forms gets submitted again. How can I handle this? after submission of a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to prevent duplicate submission of forms then use `token` interceptor http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/token-interceptor.html or `tokenSession` interceptor http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/token-session-interceptor.html.

If you simple want to refresh the page after submit without submitting again then redirect to action where you only show results not form. Use `redirectAction` result for that.

Comment: Link given doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to both the other answers.

**[Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)** is the classic Pattern for every web technology.

**[Token Interceptor](http://www.programr.com/Struts/Using_Token_Interceptor)** is another way to go, when you are using Struts2;

There is a third way to go, if you don't care about retro-compatibility with old browsers, or browsers with Javascript disabled: **HTML5**'s `window.history.pushState`.

Just reset the url to the original one after the page is loaded, and pressing F5 will get the original page, instead of re-submitting the request.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   window.history.pushState("","", "myOriginalUrlWithNoParams");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`POST REDIRECT GET`

This pattern needs to be followed to prevent re-submission of form on refresh. This means, after submitting a `POST` request, `POST` should send a `REDIRECT` response to fetch the destination page using `GET`. With this pattern, if the user refreshes the page, only the GET request happens again, so the same page is fetched without updating anything in server.

This is a common design pattern recommended for web. Google would provide a lot of resources about this.