# each refresh changes the value in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2

I am working on struts2 along with jsp for view purpose, here I am facing one issue. Whenever I refresh the value in database are  getting changed so when I tried to retrieve the values on to jsp, it gives me those changed values, which is not the one I wanted I actually want when I click only that time it should get changed not when I refresh. Any idea how to sort it out? any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.rajesh.action;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DepositAction extends ActionSupport {

private int accountno;
private String username;
private String password;
private String amount;
private int dataamount = 0;

public int getDataamount() {

return dataamount;
}

public void setDataamount(int dataamount) {
this.dataamount = dataamount;
}

public int getAccountno() {
return accountno;
}

public void setAccountno(int accountno) {
this.accountno = accountno;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public String getAmount() {
return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {

Connection con = GetCon.getCon();

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from account where accountno=? and username = ? and password =?");
ps.setInt(1, accountno);
ps.setString(2, username);
ps.setString(3, password);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

boolean status = rs.next();

System.out.println(status);

if (status == true) {

PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("Select * from account where accountno=?");

ps1.setInt(1, accountno);

ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();

if (rs1.next()) {
dataamount = Integer.parseInt(amount) + rs.getInt(5);
System.out.println(rs1.getInt(5));
System.out.println(dataamount);

}

PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("update account set amount=? where accountno='"
                        + accountno + "'");
ps2.setInt(1, dataamount);
int state = ps2.executeUpdate();

if (state > 0)
System.out.println("AMOUNT DEPOSITED");

return SUCCESS;

} else {
return "error";
}
}
}
```

and my deposit.jsp

```
<div id="header12">
<table>
<tr><td><h4>amount deposited is:<s:property value="amount"/> Rs</h4></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><h4>your current Balance is:<s:property value="dataamount" />   Rs</h4></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and my deposit1.jsp

```
<form name=F1 onSubmit="return dil(this)" action="depositAction" method="post">
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3">
<tr><td>ACCOUNT NO:</td><td> <input type="text" name="accountno"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>USER NAME:</td><td> <input type="text" name="username"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>PASSWORD:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>AMOUNT:</td><td> <input type="text" name="amount"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code ??No one is super hero here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suffering the **double submission problem**.

Legacy way would be to use **Post/Redirect/Get**, harder way on Struts2 would be using the **Token Interceptor**, but if you aren't target old browser, just do like that:

```
<body>
    ....

    <script>
        window.history.pushState("","", location.href);
    </script>
</body>
```

This would prevent resubmitting while refreshing.

Links on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529656/1654265).