# how to avoid repeated data is getting displayed in struts2 when I refresh the page,I am using S2 anchor tag ..not using form

Tags: jsp, struts2, post-redirect-get

I am struck in problem....I have link in an anchor tag which is mapped to an action and when I click on that on that link it will display all the rows of the one of the table's data from database...and in my jsp I am using  s2 Iterator tag to display contents.So when I refresh that page again that action is executing which results in repeated data is getting displayed in jsp page....I came to know that in forms we can use token tag to do this... but I want it using anchor tag please help me.

struts.xml code:

```
<action name="displayMails" class="com.money.action.DisplayMailAction"> 
  <result name="SUCCESS" type="redirect"> </result> 
</action>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax? If not maybe you need redirect after post? See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/redirect-after-post.html.

Comment: No I am not using ajax...using only S2 anchor tag to subit

Comment: Then just redirect to some action after posting values.

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried using Redirect results it's not working..

Comment: How to do that I am new to S2 please help

Comment: Show relative part of your `struts.xml` file.

Comment: Edit your question don't put code in comments.

Comment: okay.how to map action after posting values

Comment: struts.xml code <action name="displayMails" class="com.money.action.DisplayMailAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS" type="redirect">
      </result>
 </action>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13529656/1654265

Comment: @Andrea thanks...but where to write this $(document).ready(function() {
   window.history.pushState("","", "myOriginalUrlWithNoParams");
 });  code inside jsp page?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Can you please provide one example that will help to understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                window.history.pushState("","", location.href); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- STUFF -->
    </body>
</html>
```

It works on HTML5 browsers only, if you are targeting old Internet Explorers, it won't.

Edit: added CDN for jQuery, in case it wasn't clear...

Comment: [It is the URL of your current page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp). This trick is basically saying the browser's history that the last page was not coming from a post (with its parameters), but that was opened normally. This way, pressing F5 won't trigger any double submission. It has some side-effects but it should work in the most of the cases... now try it ;)

Comment: I tried using below code $(document).ready(function() { window.history.pushState("","","localhost:8084/www.moneye.in/Inbox.jsp"); }); but still not working...please guide me any other way to do this?

Comment: First: leave `location.href`, don't manually put addresses, it is "automatic"; Second: you of course will need to import jQuery, by CDN or including jQuery JS file and import in your page (for the `$(document).ready` part); otherwise, put the script with the only `history.pushState()` at the end of the body.

Comment: Do you still have problems ? Could you accept the answer if it helped?