# Avoid duplicate Struts2 form Submission when clicking on refresh button

Tags: struts2

I am using struts 2 and i want to avoid the duplicate form submission when clicking on refresh button...After getting the result from the Action class, i am coming back to the same jsp and it holds the value entered and also the message that it has been successfully submitted but the problem is that when i refresh the page..it again tries to submit the request....for that i am trying to use Token Interceptor available in struts 2...but i think I'm missing something...

```
<package name="FOCAccept" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="focSubmitRequest" class="bpel.invoke.action.FOCAcceptAction" method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="token"/>
        <result name="invalid.token">/postfocaccept.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/postfocaccept.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/postfocaccept.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/postfocaccept.jsp</result>
        <result name="invalid" type="redirectAction">LogoutCred.action</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13529656/1654265

Answer (score -1):

I have use this and it is working fine for me...at anyhow all it's matter is the output. i have added this in the jsp and when i presses the refresh button it does not hit the controller and also makes the entered field value empty..

here is the code......
`$(document).bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {

    if(e.which === 116) {
       $("#submitRequest_pon").val("");
       $(".errorMessage").html("");
       return false;
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {

       return false;
    }
});`

Comment: ... Your solution is to hijack normal browser functionality, when there's a well-established pattern to solve the problem?!

Comment: thnaks for the reply...but how 2 do that..i tried with Token interceptor but i failed...could you please give a code example...

Comment: i have added <s:token/> in my jsp and you can see my configuration above in struts.xml...and as a clik any action on that particular jsp...it shows a error msg stating the token is invalid please retry again...