# Server side validation error message are repeated in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2 xml validaion (action-validation.xml). My problem is when I clicked the save button more than one time, the error message also appears repeatedly.
how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should prevent submitting the form (and saving the data) twice, instead of caring about the double error messages, that will go away automatically once you'll solve the *real* problem.

To prevent double form submission, disable your submit button with javascript; to prevent F5 from the landing page, use Post Redirect Get Pattern, or history.pushState(). To prevent multiple submissions even when crafted, use a token (TokenInterceptor in Struts2).

Read more:

- [4 Ways To Prevent Duplicate Form Submission](http://technoesis.net/prevent-double-form-submission/)
- [how to prevent multiple form submit from client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926863/1654265)
- [Prevent double submission of forms in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery)
- [Avoid duplicate submission of Struts 2 jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529656/1654265)