# Struts 2 JSP when i refresh action success page its again submit same value in database

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
     <action name="enquiryprocess" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="createorder" >
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/EnquiryProcess.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="manual_order" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="enquiry_process">
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/EnquiryDetails.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

when i refresh `EnquiryDetails.jsp` its submit again my previous action `EnquiryProcess.jsp` value in database

Answer (score 0):

Go to Token Interceptor concept in Struts2. **[Reference](http://www.journaldev.com/2281/struts2-token-interceptor-to-handle-double-form-submission-problem)**

**OR**

[Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is the classic Pattern for every web technology.

These will disable the double submission of form.

Reference from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529166/avoid-duplicate-submission-of-struts-2-jsp-page)**

Comment: i try these one but when page load first time its automatically show error action message.